# Typescript looking in local directory when given an absolute module name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-table

I'm currently working on a typescript project made with the typescript template for create-react-app.

I'm trying to import `react-table` into my project from a component declared in `src/components/Table.tsx`. I have verified that react-table is installed, and that it is specifically the typed version. `npm list | grep table` returns `├── @types/react-table@7.7.2`.

When I attempt to load the page, the error message I receive is `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-table' in/home/user/code/CompanyName/ProjectName/src/components`

I may be mistaken, but this suggests to me that javascript is failing to look in `node_modules` for the module. What can I do to direct the compiler toward node_modules?

My `tsconfig.json` is in the project root and is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

It's worth noting that the following import, which exists in a component declared in the `src` directory, works as expected and produces no error.:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `npm list | grep table` **only** gives `@types/react-table` but not `react-table`, there's your problem.

You **always** need the actual module, e.g. `react-table`. The `@types/` version merely downloads the typings for the module, assuming the module doesn't come with typings and someone took the time to add them to `@types/`.